# Multi touch applications using tidesdk

Tags: titanium, multi-touch, tidesdk

i need to develop a desktop multitouch application using HTML5 (Javascript & CSS3) because i can not make an adobe air application as i can not develop in actionscript am looking for tutorial using Tidesdk or titanium.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing html5 app, you will probably need to wait for the 1.3.0 release (which is coming very soon) as it will have an updated version of webkit. Keep an eye on tidesdk.org or follow tidesdk on twitter.